# Using an ArrayList<String> Adapter, how can I make a custom gridview layout that displays a colored circle?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have an array list, and whenever someone presses a button, a string is added to the array list. I want to create a custom gridview layout which displays a circle whichc is colored based off of what word is entered into the text box? Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Also, I understand I have to create a class which extends arrayasapter, but nothing is autogenerated- but I see tutorials online which show auto generated comments. This confuses be, so does anyone have the base code to an array adapter which I can edit to customize? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<String> rowItems;
private GridView gridView;
private Button button;
private EditText editText;
private CustomViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    rowItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new CustomViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.activity_ma, rowItems);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rowItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}

public class CustomViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;

    public CustomViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            ArrayList<String> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtDesc;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        String rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ma, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem);
        if (position % 2 == 1) {
            holder.txtDesc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circleone);
        } else {
            holder.txtDesc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circletwo);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}

}
```

This is my activity and array adapter.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.aaa.MainActivity" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:numColumns="3" >

</GridView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gridView1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

This is the layout for activity activity_main.xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.aaa.MainActiv" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

This will be your activity_ma.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</shape>
```

This will be the textview background circleone.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"/>

    </shape>
```

This will be the textview background circletwo.xml. Try this.